# Large Wave File not being read in Python

Tags: python, audio, wav

I am trying to do sound analysis on a file in Python, and I have a sound file from a show that is high definition and it is very large (2.39 GB). However, whenever I try to open this using the wave module, I get the following error:

```
wave.Error: unknown format: 65534
```

I got this file by converting a .ts file into a .wav file. I used the same method on standard definition shows and it worked just fine. I am able to do some analysis using

```
data = np.memmap(audioclip,dtype='h',mode='r')
```

however, this does not get accurate results, as it thinks the audioclip is 3 hours long when it is only one hour long. Any help would be appreciated, I have similar issues with different error codes, however those have not been much help to this issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: command line tool :  avprobe yourbigfile.wav  which comes bundled with avconv part of libav can spit out basic info like Duration on media files ... what does it say on your file ? ... ffprobe is an alternative to avprobe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't really know that much about python.

I googled wave.py and found the following link: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/wave.py

If you look for the function named `_read_fmt_chunk` you'll see the source of the error message. In short, the wave module only supports WAVE_FORMAT_PCM.  Format `65534` is a format called `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` defined by Microsoft and is used for multi-channel wave files. It's pretty uncommon.

I think you have a few options:

1. Find a new method of converting the file that doesn't produce `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE`
2. Modify the source for `wave.py` to support `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` - assuming the `SubFormat` field is PCM or IEEE_FLOAT that wouldn't be a big deal. From that perspective it just increases the size of the header. If it is another `SubFormat` then you'll need to run an appropriate decoder before you can even get to PCM.
3. Use another tool to convert the `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` .wav file to one which is not. `sox` may be able to handle this.

Regarding the second part of your question. It's not clear from your question how you are determining the duration of the file. But if you make incorrect assumptions about the number of channels that could be throwing you off.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just using FFMpeg to convert the 5 channel file into a 2 channel one.

Comment: @clivealton, could you please mark this as the answer... I think he deserves it!!